# What is a nominee in the jargon of opening a bank account?

Tags: banking, bank-account, terminology

I am opening a bank account for my company and in the registration form they ask about the director of the company, who is me.

After setting my details, they ask if I am a nominee. What is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

A nominee is someone who has been appointed to act as a director without having any direct involvement in the company. Definition [here](https://www.completeformations.co.uk/nominees.html) and an explanation of why the bank cares about this [here](https://www.completeformations.co.uk/nominees-bank-account.html) - in short, it’s mostly to do with money laundering regulation.